# Magento 2: load disabled category childrens

Tags: category, collection, filter, magento2.3.2

I need to get all category children of a specific category but disabled categories too.

I have this category tree:

```
+ Root (ID: 2) // enabled
| + Main 1 (ID: 3) // enabled
| | + Sub 1 (ID: 4) // enabled
| + Main 2 (ID: 5) // enabled
| | + Sub 2 (ID: 6) // enabled
| + Main 3 (ID: 7) // disabled
```

I need to get all childrens of category with ID 2 [Main1(3),Main2(5),Main3(7)].

I tried with:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$parentCategoryId = 2;
$parentCategory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($parentCategoryId);

/*
Also tried with:
$parentCategory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->getCollection()
    ->addIdFilter($parentCategoryId)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', false/0/null/2) // always return an empty array...
    ->getFirstItem();
*/

$parentCategory->getChildren(); // return [3,5]

$cats = [];
foreach($parentCategory->getChildrenCategories() as $cat)
    $cats[] = $cat->getId();

print_r($cats); // return [3,5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below collection.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$parentCategoryId = 2;
$parentCategory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($parentCategoryId);


    $collection =$objectManager->create("\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory")->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                      ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
              ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',array("in"=>array('0', '1')))
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',['eq'=>$parentCategoryId]);

        print_r($collection->getData());
```

I Hope It's Will Helpful.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately always return 3 and 5, not 7. :(

Comment: Please try after clean cache and reindex

Comment: Yes, I did... No changes...

Comment: Now, can you try with update code, I have working it.

Comment: $parentCategoryId is 2, but nothing... no changes

Comment: Did you flush cache ?

Comment: Yes.. c:c, c:f, indexer:reindex

Comment: Please check attach screen short category id :5 is in-active on printed array.

Comment: Can you try to active and again inactive category. it it is working fine then make chages at               ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',array("in"=>array('0', '1'))) to               ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',array("in"=>array('0', '1',null)))

Comment: Yes it work now.. Thank you, I appreciate your help